# What is the best way to deal with spawncampers?

Tags: quake-2

While playing some multiplayer FPSs, I sometimes run into spawn campers (for those of you who don't know, this is camping at a spawn point and killing players before they have a chance to react).
At best, this is extremely annoying, and at worst, it's a form of cheating.

The only way I've found to deal with them is talk to them via the chat and try to get them to move, but that usually doesn't work. Also it takes a long time for the other players (who find an uncamped spawn point) to find and kill him, while your kill/death ratings go to hell.

Mainly this is a problem playing [DigitalPaint](http://www.digitalpaint.org) (a Quake II conversion)

Is there a good strategy to take care of spawn campers?

Comment: Newer games generally don't have this problem (team spawns occur in waves, you can pick where you're spawning, or you're invisible or invulnerable briefly on spawning), what game are you referring to?  At present this question seems unanswerable.

Comment: I agree, this seems to be game-dependant, so I'm closing this. Can you elaborate with a specific game or series of games that you have in mind?

Comment: @Mana added....

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver Thanks. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the game permits this kind of behaviour, there isn't a great deal you can do directly. You could try asking in chat if any of the server admins are online (without initially mentioning your complaint until you've engaged an admin). Basically don't say anything to the offending player(s) - that will only encourage them to continue by informing them that it's bothering you, and bothering you is almost certainly one of their objectives as much as score boosting. Knowing the psychology of these idiots is helpful in defeating them.

If you can't find an admin and your game is being ruined, find another server. Bookmark/Fave (can't remember if Q2 supports this) some trustworthy servers that you've had good experiences in, and try and join those ones. I do this with BF3, and I have 15-20 servers running various maps/modes which attract good, sportsmanlike players, and frequently have admins present kicking out the trash.